# Git filter-branch to remove sensative data not working on windows

Tags: git, github

I has an experimental project on the go, and as I was only using it locally, I added to sensitive data (secrets and connection strings). I now want to purge this data from the git history before I push the repo remotely. I have been trying to follow the github [guide](https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/) to do this, and have tried running this command:

> git filter-branch --index-filter \"git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch C:\Users\George\Source\Repos\myExperimentalProj\server\config.ts" \ --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all

I also tried -

> git filter-branch --index-filter \"git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch .\server\config.ts" \ --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all

However I always get this error:

```
fatal: ambiguous argument 'rm': unknown revision or path not in the working tree.
Use '--' to separate paths from revisions, like this:
'git <command> [<revision>...] -- [<file>...]'
```

I am using Windows command prompt with `git version 2.8.1.windows.1`.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: As far as I understand, ``\`` in referenced guide is used to escape newline (as line continuation character), but you did not put newline after ``\``.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The purpose of the `"` around the argument after `--index-filter` is to have the whole string treated as a single argument.  You're defeating that by escaping the first `"` (i.e. putting a `\` right before the `"`), causing a confusing interpretation of the command line that leads to this error.  Try again without the `\`

Comment: That seems to have completed and worked ( as in it took a while and cycled through a load of commits). However, at the end it printed out a load of warnings e.g. `WARNING: Ref 'refs/remotes/origin/master' is unchanged`, but for every branch, so it doesn't seem to have changed anything?

Comment: That would indicate that it never found (in any commit) the config.ts file.  The path should be relative to the work tree root.  An absolute path (like your 1st example) definitely won't work for an index filter.  The 2nd example, the leading `./` shouldn't be needed (though I don't really know if it hurts anything)... if that's the full path *from the repo root directory* to the file, then the relative path should work - but like I said, maybe try it without the `./`

Answer (score -1):

have you followed this guide on github help.
https://help.github.com/articles/removing-files-from-a-repository-s-history/
that page also contains this as a reference which might suit your case
https://help.github.com/articles/removing-sensitive-data-from-a-repository/